# Сложный запрос

Tags: mysql

Имеется масив, состоящий их **строковых** данных

допустим:

```
$arr[0]='hello'; $arr[1]='world';
```

Требуется вывести из таблицы бд mysql все записи, определённая ячейка которых соответствует одному из элементов массива:

```
mysql_query("SELECT title FROM $table WHERE value=*Одному из значений*$arr[]");
```

*Далее сложнее.*

Для ячеек, в которых `value` равен **последнему** элементу массива, надо вернуть не только `title`, но и, допустим, `descrition` (одну или несколько дополнительный ячеек). На примере выше, для всех строк со значением `value='world'` требуется вернуть не только `title`, но и `description`.

*Далее ещё сложнее.*

Допустим, каждая запись имеет свой уникальный id и значение родителя *(его id)*, что бы иметь возможность обратиться к нему. Можно ли выводить исключительно те записи из БД, в которых не только значение value соответствует значению элемента массива, но и значение ***value *родителя **соответствует значению** предыдущего* элемента массива***.

Возможно ли такое вообще в mysql? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Требуется вывести Далее сложнее Далее ещё сложнее.
Это что, одним запросом?

Comment: 1. "...в которых не только значение value соответствует значению элемента массива, но и значение value родителя соответствует значению предыдущего элемента массива." Все ж таки следует держать таблицы БД хотя бы в 3-ей НФ.
2. Рекомендовал бы засунуть массив в таблицу, а строки этой таблицы перенумеровть; тогда не придется в запросе приводить значения VALUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `mysql_query("SELECT title FROM $table WHERE value in ('".implode("','", $arr)."')");`
2. `mysql_query("SELECT title, description FROM $table WHERE value='".$arr[sizeof($arr)-1]."'");`
3. `mysql_query("SELECT title, description FROM $table WHERE value='".$arr[sizeof($arr)-1]."'" and (SELECT id FROM $table where value='".$arr[sizeof($arr)-2]."'));`, хотя вот тут не уверен.

Comment: 1ое - то.

Насчёт второго и третьего, вы видимо неверно меня поняли, но ладно, в целом я получил ответ на свой вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Так как вопрос про MySQL, то соответственно отвечаю по MySQL, соответственно ответ №1

```
SELECT title FROM $table WHERE value in ('hello','world')
```

ответ №2

```
SELECT title,description FROM $table WHERE value='world'
```

ответ №3

Не совсем понял вопрос, если не сложно, проиллюстрируйте, что вы хотите получить.
Хранение деревьев в MySQL (как впрочем и в других реляционных БД) - занятие не совсем простое. Посмотрите для начала хотя бы сюда: [Работа с MySQL. Деревья](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/2002-06-03).

Comment: №1 - массив разумеется динамический...
№2 - мне нужно выводить description ТОЛЬКО для соответствий последним элементом массива. Данные на практике будут большие и выводить их для каждого соответствия - неэффективно.
По №3 уже не стану ничего писать...

Comment: @Getans, для динамических данных динамически формируете текст SQL. (покрывает №№ 1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

На 3й вопрос, как-то так:

```
$arr = array( 'hello', 'world', 'of', 'mysql' );
$sql = '
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `child_value` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );

  INSERT INTO `child_value` ( `value` )
  VALUES
    ("'.implode('"),("', $arr).'");

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `parent_value` 
  SELECT * FROM `child_value`;

  SELECT `child`.*
  FROM
    `table` as `child`,
    `table` as `parent`,
    `child_value`,
    `parent_value`
  WHERE
    `child`.`value` = `child_value`.`value` AND
    `child`.`parent_id` = `parent`.`id` AND
    `parent`.`value` = `parent_value`.`value` AND
    `parent_value`.`id` = ( `child_value`.`id` - 1 )
';

echo $sql;
```